# imagejpeg() directory writing error with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, file-io

I'm getting the following error when trying to save an image

```
Unable to open '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/profile_images/' for writing:
Is a directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/user.php on line 538
```

This is the line of code that's giving me trouble

```
imagejpeg($image, "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/profile_images/".$userid);
```

I'm running XAMPP on a mac and mysql.

So far I've done the following:

1. Opened the directory options and set everyone's access to read/write
2. checked php.ini and made sure safe_mode was set to off
3. chmod 777 to said folder

Any other suggestions?

Just in case I used chmod wrong, this is exactly what I typed

```
su root
chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/profile_images
```

Comment: I think that you are going to need to show more code, but my first hunch is that `$userid` is empty.

Comment: Have an upvote for my stupidity/tiredness. I think it's time to walk away from the keyboard for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

imagejpeg needs a filename at second parameter

```
imagejpeg ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )
```

You are pointing to a directory, not a filename